# Error en la conexion de mysql Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

Estoy realizando una conexion a mi db en mysql con eclipse ide pero el problema es cuando la agrego me sale un signo de alerta sobre el proyecto al momento de agregar y me lanza el error de
Error de conexion : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver y la conexion esta de la siguiente manera.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CConexion {
    
    Connection conn = null;

    public Connection getConexion() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tienda", "root", null);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error de conexion en wc get " + e);
            Logger.getLogger(CConexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión del driver de MySQL usas? Y ¿Ya importaste ese driver a tu proyecto?

Comment: @Edgar Gc , Si ya lo importe como jar lo cree como librería de varias maneras pero al hacer eso y aplicar la librería me muestra un triángulo amarillo en el proyecto, use la versión 5.1.14 y la 8.0.21 y con las dos me pasa lo mismo

Comment: Por cierto, tienes una `C` de mas en tu clase `Conexion`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es que debas agregar una lineá como esta después del nombre de la base de datos.

```
 + "useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Entonces, podrías definir tu clase de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Conexion {
    Connection conectar = null;

    public Connection obtenerConexion() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            System.out.println("Registrado");
            System.out.println("");

            conectar = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/tienda?"
                    + "useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&user=root&password=tupassword");
            System.out.println("Conectado");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("\n Error");
        }
        return conectar;
    }

    public void cerrarConexion() {
        try {
            conectar.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Debo aclarar que estoy usando la versión 8.0 y java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente si no encuentra la clase es porque no añadiste el driver al build path.
Tenes que ir al proyecto,click boton derecho,build path,java build path,class path,add external jars,y ahi añadis el driver.